# Setting primary identity in ClaimsPrincipal.Current

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, identity, claims-based-identity

How to change in ClaimsPrincipal.Current identity collection the primary one identity ?
I saw there is ClaimsPrincipal.PrimaryIdentitySelector, but I am not sure when it is fired and how it have to work.

As I sow I can only add a new one ClaimIndetity to the collection, but I can not set it as primary. If I can not do that then default Account control in MVC does not see provided user name .

Thank you,
Rastko

Comment: For Thread.CurrentPrincipal in Account:  
Base type is System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal?  
Identities.Count = 1 or more?  
Identity type is System.Security.Principal.ClaimsIdentity?  
In identity what is a value for NameClaimType (for example "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name")?  
in Identity.Claims do you have related claims with same value type?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Identities, and lets say only one of them has a name claim. You could do this.

```
public class MyPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public MyPrincipal() 
    {
        PrimaryIdentitySelector = (ids) => ids.FirstOrDefault(id => id.Name == ClaimTypes.Name);
    }
}
```

}